# Center align the absolute div without using left:0, right:0, width:100%

Tags: html, css

How to center a `absolute div` without using `left`, `right` and `width:100%`? And the `width` should be `auto`

```
div{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Generally, when not setting a `left` and `top`, it is up to the browser to decide which initial value those properties will have. Based on that, there is no _stabil_ way to accomplish what you ask. You might want to explain why those properties can't be used? ... School project? ... Also, center it horizontal, vertical or both?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, center it on horizontal, If width:auto; means we can access back side elements, When we use left, right property which takes 100% of width.

Comment: Don,t use any parent relative element, absolute div should relative to the body element

Comment: So what you say is that we can use `left` as long as we don't use it in a way that it cover the behind element on left/right side of the centered element?

Comment: Behind elements takes 100% of the page, Meanwhile, absolute element appearance we can access both elements.

Comment: Okay, so yo need to be more specific about the meaning of _without using left, right and width:100%_, since `left` and `top` is going to be needed to solve this, but it can be done in a way where you can access an element behind.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
.answer {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 50% 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="answer">absolute</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your snippets,when answer text increase dynamically it will expanding to right side only

Answer (score 0):

I just centered this horizontally as OP didn't state whether it is centered horizontally or vertically

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:blue;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, 0);
  width: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> SAMPLE CONTENT </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `margin` to position your div element. For example:

```
margin-left: 50%;
```

or viceversa.

**EDIT:** Here is a snippet to explain the above text. I hope it helps.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #000;
}

h1 {
color: #fff;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>This is an example</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added, I hope it helps.

Comment: I think `h1` is not centered